# How to Ensure Proguard Has Obfuscated Application?

Tags: android, obfuscation, reverse-engineering, proguard

My project does not enable proguard when creating it. Therefore I need to manually add proguard and enable it via project.properties.

Is there any way I can know whether my application has been obfuscated or not aside from reverse engineering?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190907/how-to-tell-if-proguard-has-done-its-job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application has been obfuscated you will see a new folder called `proguard` in you project folder.
It should contain four text files: dump, mapping, seeds and usage.

Note that your project will not be obfuscated unless you build it in release mode.

Comment: Good note about release mode, i missed that the first time using proguard

Answer (score 0):

Just for records, if you want to check if your code was really obfuscated, you can generate the APK and analyse it in this webpage: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apktool

You can check using Android Studio as well by generating the APK and later going to Build -> Analyze APK... -> select your APK to analyze.

I hope this help.